# Why does my SD card change to readonly when I mounted it as readwrite?

Tags: mount, sd-card

I've got an SD card mounted on a ip camera, which runs on linux. I set the videos to record on to the SD card, but after a few days, all my cameras' SD cards stopped recording and I noticed it was because they were all mounted as readonly. When I mount them back as readwrite, they turn into readonly right after.

I suspected it was this batch of SD cards that I bought cheap from ebay, so I tried putting them into a USB adapter into Windows, and it can read and write just fine -- I tested it by filling it with a bunch of random videos, and then copying them back out.

Here's the entry in mount -v

/dev/hd1 on /tmp/hd1 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

Any idea what's going on? This is happening to all 4 of my cameras and SD cards.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have `errors=remount-ro` specified as an option. Thus if an error occurs, you'll that find your media has become read-only.

You can replace this with `errors=continue` to ignore such errors. You probably don't want to.

If you notice it soon enough, you can check `dmesg`or other logging sources (`journalctl`?) on the "bad" system to see if such errors have occurred.